# Marketing Cloud sending Content Builder Email to List

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, list, content-builder

I have created a list (using SOAP API) and know the ID of this. The HTML Email exists in Content Builder, I know the name and the ID. How can I send the email to the list. This is not a triggered event. I'm attempting to send at thsi moment. I think the solution is REST based, but can't find documentation on how to do this, or if it's possible with APIs. Looking for a simple working sample and URI (REST I assume) of how to do this using either name or ID.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a TriggeredSend for the email in order to send an email via REST Api call, and you'll need to trigger it individually per recipient.

You can create a User-Initiated Email (thru the Ui or via SOAP) using your list and Email which you may then trigger or schedule via SOAP Api.

A couple references (more within the documentation):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_email_send_definition.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/starting_an_email_send_definition.htm

Comment: I have that all working, but only with Classic emails. I have not been able to create an EmailSendDefinition using an Email from Content Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Account -> Installed packages and create your API integration, make sure you give access to
Email:
Read, Write, Send

Using SOAP UI, create a new REST project, under there right click -> new Request.

You will need 2 requests :

Request token : see picture 1 (use cliend id and secret) from your package and click submit 
Create email: see picture 2, your access token will be the one generated in previous step

using the html paste email will work, put the json in the left handside as shown in the picture
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/asset_model_examples.htm

[image: RequestToken][image: Create Email]